# EntityManager.remove() not throwing expected exception

Tags: java, jpa

According to [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove-java.lang.Object), the `remove` method of `com.javax.persistence.EntityManager` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`

> if the instance is not an entity or **is a detached entity**

Given this, why does this code not throw an exception:

```
// create an Author object: this is a POJO
Author a = new Author("George Orwell");
dao.delete(a);
```

where the `delete` method of the `DAO` is simply

```
public void delete(T entity) throws IllegalArgumentException, TransactionRequiredException {
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.remove(entity);
  em.getTransaction().commit();
 }
```

If I add the line

```
System.out.println(em.contains(entity));
```

to the `delete` method, it prints `false`. This seems to be the definition of a "detached entity", so why is no exception thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't delete a detached entity :

```
Author a = new Author("George Orwell");  // transient entity

dao.delete(a); // delete an entity unknown for the context. 
               // The EM silently ignores that
```

It deletes a transient entity, that is an entity that never was managed by the persistence context.

To delete a detached entity, first make it attached to the persistence context :

```
Author a = new Author("George Orwell");  // transient entity

em.refresh(a); // attach the entity to the persistence context. 
               // persist() or merge() would also attach it

em.detach(a);  // detach it from the context

em.delete(a);  // delete a detached entity.
               // The EM throws llegalArgumentException
```

An `IllegalArgumentException` should so be thrown if your JPA implementation respects the specification.

At least, that is what Hibernate does to process the `delete()` operation :

```
package org.hibernate.event.internal;
...
public class DefaultDeleteEventListener implements DeleteEventListener {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void performDetachedEntityDeletionCheck(DeleteEvent event) {
        EventSource source = event.getSession();
        String entityName = event.getEntityName();
        EntityPersister persister = source.getEntityPersister( entityName, event.getObject() );
        Serializable id =  persister.getIdentifier( event.getObject(), source );
        entityName = entityName == null ? source.guessEntityName( event.getObject() ) : entityName; 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Removing a detached instance "+ entityName + "#" + id);
    }
    ...
}
```